# AngularEditor: ViewChild removed after successful file upload?

Tags: wysiwyg, angular8, image-upload, viewchild, execcommand

I would like to use https://github.com/kolkov/angular-editor, but there is a problem:
I want to upload images, this seems to work fine, request to/from backend looks good.

There is an `ElementRef myInputFile`:

```js
myInputFile: [{ type: _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["ViewChild"], args: ['fileInput', { static: true },] }]
```

that's connected to `fileInput`:

```html
<input
      style="display: none"
      accept="image/*"
      type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)"
      #fileInput>
```

`onFileChanged` is implement something like this:

```js
onFileChanged(event) {
        /** @type {?} */
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        if (file.type.includes('image/')) {
            if (this.uploadUrl) {
                this.editorService.uploadImage(file).subscribe((/**
                 * @param {?} e
                 * @return {?}
                 */
                e => {
                    if (e instanceof _angular_common_http__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["HttpResponse"]) {
                        this.editorService.insertImage(e.body.imageUrl);
                        this.fileReset();
                    }
                }));
            }
            else {
                /** @type {?} */
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = (/**
                 * @param {?} e
                 * @return {?}
                 */
                (e) => {
                    /** @type {?} */
                    const fr = (/** @type {?} */ (e.currentTarget));
                    this.editorService.insertImage(fr.result.toString());
                });
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
        }
    }
```

So at some point `this.fileReset()` is being called

```js
fileReset() {
        this.myInputFile.nativeElement.value = '';
    }
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is a library bug. Should be fixed soon:

https://github.com/kolkov/angular-editor/issues/178